# SCCM remove previous Versions of Java

Tags: java, batch-file, sccm

I am trying to use a task sequence to remove previous versions of Java. I am using the command line feature in the Task sequence as so:
[image]

Inside the script its pretty basic. It is :

```
msiexec /x {26a24ae4-039d-4ca4-87b4-2f86418001f0} /q /norestart
msiexec /x {26a24ae4-039d-4ca4-87b4-2f86418002f0} /q /norestart
msiexec /x {26a24ae4-039d-4ca4-87b4-2f86418003f0} /q /norestart
msiexec /x {26a24ae4-039d-4ca4-87b4-2f86418004f0} /q /norestart
msiexec /x {26a24ae4-039d-4ca4-87b4-2f86418005f0} /q /norestart
```

Then I deploy the task sequence and it loads on the computer but it never runs. it freezes up and i get no error code back. Thanks for any of the help i can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trying to run a batch file from a network location, you need to use cmd.exe to call the batch file, like:
cmd.exe /c ***.bat

Comment: Sorry im getting back so late. we had some big projects come up but this worked!